# QObject::connect crash at signalOffset(senderMetaObject) due to QMetaObject::superdata contains null data

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, signals-slots

My connection code is as following:

```
QObject::connect(_scene, &VScene::activeObjectChanged, _scene->manipulatorNode(), &VManipulatorNode::onActiveObjectChanged);
```

`VScene` is subclass of `VNode`, which is a subclass of `QObject`. Both of them contain the `Q_OBJECT` macro.

#### VScene is the signal sender:

```
class VScene : public VNode
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public slots:
    void        markActiveObject(VObject *obj);
    void        unmarkActiveObject(VObject *obj);
signals:
    void        activeObjectChanged(VObject *obj);
}
```

#### VNode:

```
class VNode : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
}
```

#### VManipulator:

```
class VManipulatorNode : public VNode
{
public:
    void onActiveObjectChanged(VObject *obj);
}
```

The program crashes while calling `QObject::connect`, at the function

```
    signal_index += QMetaObjectPrivate::signalOffset(senderMetaObject);
```

Whiling debugging, I found out that the  `superdata`pointer of the `QMetaObject` of the sender `VScene` contains only null data.

I see that `QMetaObject` of `VScene` will point to `QMetaObject` of `VNode`, and then, `QMetaObject` of `VNode` will point to `QMetaObject` of `QObject`. Here, at the crash position, `QMetaObject` of `VScene` contains only null data

All moc files, including `moc_VScene` and `moc_VNode`, are generated normally by Qt.

#### moc_VScene.cpp:

```
const QMetaObject vk::VScene::staticMetaObject = {
{ &VNode::staticMetaObject, qt_meta_stringdata_vk__VScene.data,
  qt_meta_data_vk__VScene,  qt_static_metacall, Q_NULLPTR, Q_NULLPTR}
};
```

#### moc_VNode.cpp:

```
struct qt_meta_stringdata_vk__VNode_t {
QByteArrayData data[1];
char stringdata0[10];
};
#define QT_MOC_LITERAL(idx, ofs, len) \
    Q_STATIC_BYTE_ARRAY_DATA_HEADER_INITIALIZER_WITH_OFFSET(len, \
    qptrdiff(offsetof(qt_meta_stringdata_vk__VNode_t, stringdata0) + ofs \
    - idx * sizeof(QByteArrayData)) \
)
static const qt_meta_stringdata_vk__VNode_t qt_meta_stringdata_vk__VNode = {
    {
        QT_MOC_LITERAL(0, 0, 9) // "vk::VNode"
    },
    "vk::VNode"
};
#undef QT_MOC_LITERAL

static const uint qt_meta_data_vk__VNode[] = {

 // content:
   7,       // revision
   0,       // classname
   0,    0, // classinfo
   0,    0, // methods
   0,    0, // properties
   0,    0, // enums/sets
   0,    0, // constructors
   0,       // flags
   0,       // signalCount

   0        // eod
};

void vk::VNode::qt_static_metacall(QObject *_o, QMetaObject::Call _c, int     _id, void **_a)
{
    Q_UNUSED(_o);
    Q_UNUSED(_id);
    Q_UNUSED(_c);
    Q_UNUSED(_a);
}

const QMetaObject vk::VNode::staticMetaObject = {
    { &QObject::staticMetaObject, qt_meta_stringdata_vk__VNode.data,
  qt_meta_data_vk__VNode,  qt_static_metacall, Q_NULLPTR, Q_NULLPTR}
};
```

NOTE: while debugging in Visual Studio, it's shown that `VNode::staticMetaObject`contains only null data, but it's so strange that all of its static member  including `qt_meta_stringdata_vk__VNode` and `qt_meta_data_vk__VNode` look right (non-null). Here is the evidence
[image]

The code emitting signal:

```
void VScene::markActiveObject(VObject *obj)
{
    if (obj){
        obj->markActive();
        emit activeObjectChanged(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm just basing this on what I've read of the official Qt examples (having never coded in it). Aren't you mean to call `connect` with your arguments wrapped by `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros? and you haven't marked your slot using the `slot` macro. and this being Qt, there are probably _more_ cryptic macros needed somewhere else.

Comment: @underscore_d, since Qt5 it is better to connect via method pointers, not `SIGNAL`/`SLOT` macros

Comment: @AndreiR Thanks, I'm glad they're modernising some bits of the the API. They really ought to update their tutorials/examples, then... which claim to be for QT 5.6 but still use the old `connect` syntax (nearly?) everywhere.

Comment: AndreiR  is right, this is an improvement from Qt5. https://woboq.com/blog/new-signals-slots-syntax-in-qt5.html

Comment: Have you tried this without passing `VObject *` parameter ... i.e. remove the parameter from the slot / signal fictions just to see if it works. The reason I suggest this is that normally you have to register your custom types with qRegisterMetaObject (I think its called that)... however I am not sure if inheriting QObject resolves this or not...

Comment: @khanhhh89 Thank you for the link! Those are some _massive_ improvements to signal connection (versus a low baseline). But I have to laugh at: "Which one is the more beautiful is a matter of taste." It's really not: proper C++ syntax and compile-time checking is objectively superior to macro- and runtime string hackery. So I'm glad to see they're starting to move in that direction. Anyway, sorry, I'll stop rambling on your question now :-)

Comment: Can you post your code for `VScene::manipulatorNode()` and for where you `emit activeObjectChanged()`

Comment: @code_fodder: I have updated the question, add the code you requested, and provide more information about the null static moc data

Comment: @khanhhh89 But I can't see, in your VScene header, your member function `manipulatorNode()` You have posted the implementation but it does not appear in your header - is that missing or you just have not posted it?  What I mean is `_scene` is type `VScene` and you call somthing called `_scene->manipulatorNode()` where is that?

Comment: @ code_fodder: I just simplify the code. All the pointer _scene and _scene->manipulatorNode are valid.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I notice is that you should change:

```
public:
    void onActiveObjectChanged(VObject *obj);
```

to:

```
public slots:
    void onActiveObjectChanged(VObject *obj);
```

Not sure from the info given if that will solve it, but it is not right.

Comment: I tried it, but it still crash. But QT document allows slot function is any kind of function

Comment: Actually you are right, you can use any function.. the only real difference is that when you use the SLOT macro (or view members list in auto complete) this function shows as a slot.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue. If it's the same cause, I believe it is related to [QTBUG-38876](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-38876). In my case the signal/slot connections were being created in the constructor of a static object. Delaying the connection to occur after global statics have been initialised solved the issue for me.